# Type of context-type application json flutter

Tags: flutter

I get problem in when I use postman to post api
the header need to be 'Content-Type : application/json'

In First I test with post api token and result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhC0k.png)

after that I do the same with other api but result is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idBp0.png)

both of api get success but after I post api one and two I got problem cause

they need application/json but in my flutter it's get application/json;charset=UTF8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcyzB.png)

Comment: My point is I want to make application/json only in flutter app

Comment: when I change application/json; charset=utf-8 to postman I it will get code 415

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your code its `content-types` Instead of `Content-Type` maybe check there